# How to run Celery and Django web app simultaneously on Railway?

Tags: django, deployment, railway

I'm trying to deploy a Django web application along with Celery for background task processing on Railway. I've configured my railway.json deployment file as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://railway.app/railway.schema.json",
  "build": {
    "builder": "NIXPACKS"
  },
  "deploy": {
    "startCommand": "celery -A core worker --loglevel=INFO && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn core.wsgi --timeout 60",
    "numReplicas": null,
    "healthcheckPath": null,
    "healthcheckTimeout": null,
    "restartPolicyType": "ON_FAILURE",
    "restartPolicyMaxRetries": 10,
    "cronSchedule": null
  }
}
```

However, with this configuration, only Celery starts, and the Django web server (gunicorn) doesn't seem to run. How can I adjust my deployment configuration to ensure that both Celery and the Django web app start and run simultaneously?

I've tried rearranging the `startCommand`, placing `celery` at the end, but it doesn't seem to work. Any guidance or best practices for configuring Celery and Django web app deployments on Railway would be greatly appreciated.